# Does Hiei transform into his Jaganshi form more than once in the anime?

Tags: yu-yu-hakusho

In the anime, before The Beasts of Maze Castle arc, when Hiei and Yusuke fight for the first time, he had a transformation called the Jaganshi form which increased his speed and power.

The only other time we see this form is in the movie *Poltergeist Report*.

In all the other fights (excluding The Beasts of Maze Castle, because he wasn't even breaking a sweat there): The Dark Tournament, The Chapter Black, The Demon World Tournament, he never used it again.

Is there a canonical reason for this? Or was it just forgotten about?